# Arduino void loop() stopped working after HttpClient request

Tags: arduino

I have an access control system that retrieves data from the database, the problem is if the RFID is not registered on the database, it gets stuck there and it does not scan for the RFID card anymore.

The same scenario when both the RFID and PIN Code matches with the database.
The loop stopped working after I have used Ethernet and HttpClient libraries.

Here's is my program code:

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <ArduinoHttpClient.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <Servo.h>

/////// RFID Settings ///////
#define SS_PIN 53
#define RST_PIN 10
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);   // Create MFRC522 instance.

/////// Ethernet Settings ///////
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 222);
char serverAddress[] = "192.168.1.51";  // server address
int port = 80;

/////// HttpClient Settings ///////
EthernetClient ethr;
HttpClient client = HttpClient(ethr, serverAddress, port);
int statusCode = 0;

/////// Keypad Settings ///////
char key[4];
int i = 0;
String pass;
const byte ROWS = 4; // Four rows
const byte COLS = 4; // columnsffff
// Define the Keymap
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};
// Connect keypad ROW0, ROW1, ROW2 and ROW3 to these Arduino pins.
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {29, 28, 27, 26}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad
byte colPins[COLS] = {25, 24, 23, 22}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad
Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

/////// Servo Settings ///////
Servo lock; //declares servo

/////// Status Variables & Strings ///////
int rStatus = 0; // RFID Status
int pStatus = 0; // PIN Status
String getReq, tag, rfid, pincode;

void setup() {
  /////// Starting Serial ///////
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(1000);

  /////// Ethernet Setup ///////
  Serial.println("Initializing Ethernet.");
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  Serial.println("Connection Success.");
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);

  /////// RFID Setup ///////
  Serial.println("Initializing RFID Module.");
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();   // Initiate MFRC522
  Serial.println("RFID Ready.");
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);

  /////// Keypad Setup ///////
  Serial.println("Initializing Keypad Module...");
  keypad.addEventListener(keypadEvent); //add an event listener for this keypad
  Serial.println("Keypad Ready.");
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);

  /////// Servo Setup ///////
  Serial.println("Setting up servo motor...");
  lock.attach(13);
  Serial.println("Servo Motor Ready.");
  Serial.println("");
  delay(1000);

  /////// R E A D Y ///////
  Serial.println("Please tap RFID Card.");
}

void loop() {
  if (rStatus == 0)
  {
    readRFID();
  }
  else if (rStatus == 1)
  {
    keypad.getKey();
  }

  if (rStatus == 1 && pStatus == 1)
  {
    Serial.println("Door Unlocked.");
    lock.write(5);
    delay(5000);
    lock.write(0);
    rStatus = 0;
    pStatus = 0;
    delay(1000);
    loop();
  }
}

/////// Module Methods - RFID ///////
void readRFID()
{
  // Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent())
  {
    return;
  }
  // Select one of the cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial())
  {
    return;
  }
  //Show UID on serial monitor
  Serial.print("RFID UID : ");
  String content = "";
  for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++)
  {
    content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i]));
  }
  Serial.println(content);
  tag = String(content);
  getTagRequest();
  Serial.print("DB UID : ");
  Serial.println(rfid);

  if (tag == rfid) //change here the UID of the card/cards that you want to give access
  {
    Serial.print("Message : ");
    Serial.println("UID Found.");
    Serial.println();
    delay(3000);
    rStatus = 1;
    Serial.println("Please enter 4 digit PIN.");
  }

  else   {
    Serial.println(" Access denied");
    delay(3000);
    rStatus = 0;
  }
}

/////// Module Methods - Keypad ///////
void keypadEvent(KeypadEvent eKey)
{

  switch (keypad.getState())
  {
    case PRESSED:

      key[i] = eKey;
      Serial.print("Enter: ");
      Serial.println(eKey);
      delay(10);
      i++;

      switch (eKey)
      {
        case '#': checkPassword(); delay(1); break;

        case '*': i = 0; delay(1); break;

        default: delay(1);
      }
  }
}

void checkPassword()
{
  pass = "";
  pass.concat(key[0]);
  pass.concat(key[1]);
  pass.concat(key[2]);
  pass.concat(key[3]);

  delay(1000);
  getPinRequest();

  Serial.print("Input PIN: ");
  Serial.println(pass);
  Serial.print("DB PIN: ");
  Serial.println(pincode);

  if (pass == pincode)
  {


    Serial.println("Message: PIN Accepted");
    Serial.println("");
    i = 0;
    pStatus = 1;
    delay(10);
  } else
  {
    Serial.println("Message: PIN Denied"); //if passwords wrong keep box locked
    i = 0;
    pStatus = 0;
    delay(10);
  }
}

/////// Database Transactions via PHP ///////
void getTagRequest() {
  //Making GET Request
  getReq = "";
  getReq.concat("/getTag.php?tag=");
  getReq.concat(tag);
  client.get(getReq);
  rfid = client.responseBody();

  client.stop();
  delay(1000);
}

void getPinRequest() {
  //Making GET Request
  getReq = "";
  getReq.concat("/getPin.php?tag=");
  getReq.concat(tag);
  getReq.concat("&pin=");
  getReq.concat(pass);
  client.get(getReq);
  pincode = client.responseBody();

  client.stop();
  delay(1000);
}
```

So how do I fix this? I want the system to ask again for an RFID Card after having matched results from the db.

Comment: Why are you calling `loop();` from within the loop?

Comment: i was just trying it since the loop stops working after the system works thinking it might call out itself and starts to loop again, sadly it did not work

Comment: So if you put a `Serial.Println("loop");` at the top of the loop, that message only appears once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out by not using any pins on my ethernet shield except for the 5v/3.3v and the GND only. It now works again and loops the whole program